# DataGrid Update

Tags: database, datagridview

I got this method for updating my database. I would like to choose for example some cells from table and update it, for example i want to change cells (ID[1], Name[Peter], LastName[Holg])------>[ID[2], Name[Rob], LastName[Clein]) but i dont know how i can select them in datagrids.

table:  ID_Customer / Name / Lastname

```
public void Customer()
    {
        DataTable update = new DataTable("Customer");
        update.Columns.Add("ID_Customer");
        update.Columns.Add("Name");
        update.Columns.Add("LastName");

        Cust_Map customer= new Cust_Map();

        Customer customer1= new Customer ();
        customer1.ID_Customer = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[0].Value);
        customer1.Name = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[1].Value);
        customer1.LastName = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[2].Value);


        update.Rows.Add(customer1.ID_Customer, customer1.Name, customer1.LastName);
        customer.Update(customer1.ID_Customer, customer1.Name, customer1.LastName);

    }
```

Comment: You either select them via an event on the GUI (like single/double click) or via code. Which one do you want?

Comment: i would like single click for sure

Comment: I assume that you bind your datatable to a dataGridView. If so, you can add an event for single click to identify the row clicked, use this information to change the values in the datatable.